# Update statement with inner join on Oracle ORA-01427

Tags: sql, oracle

```
UPDATE Team 
SET Team_name = CONCAT((SELECT Team_name 
                        FROM Team 
                        INNER JOIN Coach ON Team.Coach_id = Coach.Coach_id 
                        WHERE Coach_name = 'Sidny Jonson'), '_nure') ;
```

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row ORA-06512:
> at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

I need to do update with inner join in ORACLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you provided above is going to update all rows in the table because you do not have a where clause. If you really want to update all rows in the table, then this should work.

```
UPDATE team SET team_name = team_name||'_nure';
```

If you **only** want to update the rows for coach Sidny Jonson, then this should work.

```
UPDATE team SET team_name = team_name||'_nure' where coach_id in (select coach_id from Coach where Coach_name = 'Sidny Jonson');
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like

```
update team a set
  a.team_name = a.team_name || '_nure'
where exists (select null 
              from coach b
              where b.coach_id = a.coach_id
                and b.coach_name = 'Sidny Jonson'
             );
```

or - using `merge`:

```
merge into team a
  using coach b
  on (a.coach_id = b.coach_id)
when matched then update set
  a.team_name = a.team_name || '_nure'
  where b.coach_name = 'Sidny Jonson';
```